# sshfs abrupt disconnection

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, sshfs

I am doing a lot of coding over SSH and so I have decided to mount the file system via `sshfs`:

```
user@remote /home/user/mnt fuse.sshfs noauto,_netdev,users,idmap=user,reconnect 0 0
```

If my internet connection breaks, my local machine 'freezes'. Since internet connection instabilities are rather common, I am looking for a more reliable way of mounting this file system, so that it does not affect my local machine if things go wrong. Are there special mount options that allow this?

PS: Working solely via terminal and `screen` is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I've read and reread the man page several times looking for a way to gracefully unmount an sshfs -o reconnect mount point. As I recall, the only way that works is to omit reconnect from -o.